Temperature vs Power has strong positive correlation
So, I just bought super high RPM fan for my laptop, it's worked fine, it reduced temperature.
I noticed multivariate time series real time graph between temperature and power that they have similarity drawn (of course not totally similar). But as you see when I turned on the fan, both temperature and power goes down.

While temperature is designed to know is the hardware overheating, how about power, why I need to know the state of power if I can just see temperature monitor?

so as CPUs heat up, they start producing lots of errors, which requires that work be redone. that creates a vicious spiral, where the CPU needs to pull more power, while simultaneously increasing heat and error rate. That said though, your graphs seem ... off. what is the specific temp reading you are displaying? TCase? I'd be surprised if an external fan had that much impact on Core Temp or Die Temp that quickly. Also make sure that your CPU isn't responding to the heat by throttling down the frequency, coincidental to your turning on of the fan.

Was the load constant? If not, the correlation might be that the system cooled, and therefore the fan was shut. Add load info, e.g., https://www.jam-software.com/heavyload . As for your having to observe power or temp, in most cases trust the system to handle that -- don't bother looking unless there's an issue (e.g., overclocked CPU, or lowing when hot).

Is this "Super high RPM" fan powered by USB?

@Mokubai no, powered by 12V/2A

@DrMoishePippik I'm afraid that stress software caused damage for my PC. So, the measurement in post was idle measurement.

@FrankThomas the Acer Aspire A515-44 it said that it started throttled if above 105°C
